# Customising Smooth products by Kevin Thornbloom

Tags: jquery, html, css, zooming

I've two concerns editing the jquery.

1. How to remove the Product Zoom [zoom function on hover] from Smooth products.
2. To Show a min. number of thumbnails and hide the rest. Scroll them one by one using left/ right navigation.

this is just a link to the original source : https://github.com/kthornbloom/Smoothproducts

Answer (score 0):

To remove the product zoom I would start by looking at this code in smoothproducts.js

```
// Zoom In non-touch
        $(document.body).on('mouseenter', '.sp-non-touch .sp-large', function(event) {
            var largeUrl = $('a', this).attr('href');
            $(this).append('<div class="sp-zoom"><img src="' + largeUrl + '"/></div>');
            $(this).find('.sp-zoom').fadeIn(250);
            event.preventDefault();
        });

        // Zoom Out non-touch
        $(document.body).on('mouseleave', '.sp-non-touch .sp-large', function(event) {
            $(this).find('.sp-zoom').fadeOut(250, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

To accomplish number two it sounds like you want some kind of slider.  Honestly, there is probably a better way to accomplish what you want rather than hacking away at an existing plugin.

Comment: really appreciate your time.